# Extra unwanted margin of TextViews _ android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, margins

I'm designing this `XML` file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:background="#00C7C7">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_n"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:text="@string/all"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/koohinoor_bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_title"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:text="@string/all_alphabetic_order"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/koohinoor_bold"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textColor="#3A3939"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

A `TextView` is located under the `ImageView`. Also another `TextView` is located under the first-mentioned `TextView`. I expect there be no margins between the `TextView`s and the `ImagView`, but there are extra unwanted margins...

what could be the problem? what could be the solution?

---

*notes:*

*I'm using Persian fonts.*

*In `XML` preview, no problem is observed. This issue is seen on run-time.*

Comment: please add app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" to your text view description

Comment: Dear @ManthanPatel, unfortunately, it didn't work. Please suggest any other solution if possible . . .

Comment: can you share screenshot what is output view with ths code

Answer (score 1):

> you need to add vertical bias to your textview (**description**)

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:text="@string/all_alphabetic_order"
                android:fontFamily="@font/koohinoor_bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="#3A3939"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" 
                />
```

Comment: Dear @ManthanPatel, unfortunately, it didn't work. Please suggest any other solution if possible

Answer (score 1):

First off all you can use LinearLayout for your situation. It is more effective. Also in LinearLayout you can use negative margins which you need in your case. Try this layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00C7C7"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_signal_chain_power" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/koohinoor_bold"
            android:text="@string/all"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/koohinoor_bold"
            android:text="@string/all_alphabetic_order"
            android:textColor="#3A3939"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did not know android:includeFontPadding="false" so this is a workaround but elyar abad 's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

set imageview height to  `wrap-content`

```
 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap-content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_n"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to your `TextViews`, and your done!